# list azure blobs based on metadata - python sdk

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage-account

I'm using the azure blob storage sdk and I hoped that there would be way to filter blobs based on certain metadata information.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

container_name = 'c1'
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(os.environ['STORAGE_ACCOUNT_CONNECTION_STRING'])
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

all_blobs = container_client.list_blobs(include='metadata')

for in in all_blobs:
    print('{}'.format(i.name))
```

I have several thousand blobs saved in that account and I want to make the search faster in my app - is there a way to filter based on metadata? I don't want to query all of the blobs and make a list comprehension. - thanks!

Comment: Right now there isn't an easy wat to do this. They are working on it. It is in preview: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/manage-and-find-data-with-blob-index-for-azure-storage-now-in-preview/

Comment: Hey,@Burmi. Maybe the second answer you can refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472504/azure-searching-metadata-in-blobs

Answer (score 0):

Your include needs to be a list of BlobProperties:

```
service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

blob_iter = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with=None, include=["metadata"])
for i in blob_iter:
    print(i)
```

reference see: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobproperties?view=azure-python and
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python#list-blobs-name-starts-with-none--include-none----kwargs-